# Replace nan values in a column with values from a different column from the same df in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm very new to polars and i'm trying to translate some pandas statements.

The pandas line is as follows:

```
df.loc[df['col_x'].isna(), 'col_y'] = df['col_z']
```

that is to say: replace the values of col_y corresponding to null values of col_x with values of col_z.

In polars i'm trying with *select*, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you maybe add a small dataframe? And do you have nulls or floating point NaNs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have the solution for Polars and Pandas:
Polars:

```
df = (
    df
    .with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('col_x').is_nan()).then(pl.col('col_z'))
              .otherwise(pl.col('col_y')).alias('col_y'))
)
```

Pandas:

```
df["col_y"] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['col_x']), df['col_z'], df['col_y'])
```

I hope this helps!